# Tab on focus or Tab on click Image size to be increased

Tags: android, image, tabs, onclick, onfocus

I want to have this kind of look for my tabs [image], e.g. when the user clicks on a certain tab or on focus that tab's image should get enlarged.

Comment: Tried to increase the childs height but always getting nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can muck around with tab sizes in Android, its a bit gnarly, but can be done

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 
          tabHeight;

Where childAt is the tab you want to muck with.. I generally have modified all my tabs to the same height (loop through them all) when I do this, but it should allow you to change height dynamically one at a time like you want.

Catch the user selecting it, then go set the size of the last selected back to "normal" and increase the size of the one selected.

Comment: Can you refer me to any example?

Comment: Not really, its all going to be documented with TABHOST, with the exception of how to set the width and height..  basically in your code get your tabhost TabHost th = getTabHost();   Then from the tabhost you can set the indivual tabs heights and widths via the line avaiable above.    If you need to know how to interact with tabs to do actions when a tab is selected, you need to set up a OnTabChangedListener on the tabhost, the onTabChanged event is passed the tabID of the tab that was selected.

Comment: Not only did I try it I use it in several commercial apps that have 4 and 5 star ratings.

Comment: Can you point me to the applications that you have developed this way and if it exists in Android marketplace?

Comment: I guess you never understood my question.